# using the integer difference in strcmp in c programming

Tags: c

i have this below program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char text1[30],text2[30];
    int diff;
    puts("Enter text1:");
    fgets(text1,30,stdin);
    puts("Enter text2:");
    fgets(text2,30,stdin);
    diff=strcmp(text1,text2);
    printf("Difference between %s and %s is %d",text1,text2,diff);
}
```

if i give text1  as inputtext and text2 as differencetext , then the difference should be 5 , but i am getting as 1 for different inputs ,  i am not sure where i am going wrong.

Comment: RTFM - why don't we say this to kids anymore?

Comment: have not heard that in a while now... :)

Comment: i want to find the ASCII difference between the two strings, by using strcmp  can i find the ASCII difference ?

Comment: @user2684816: You can compare the two strings by writing your own loop, character by character, and subtracting the first two characters that differ. (Guard against the case where the strings are equal.) However, why would you want to do that; of what use is the difference between two character codes? Also: Not all C implementations use ASCII. Most do (at least by default), but relying on it limits a program’s portability. Also, there is a theoretical possibility that subtracting two `char` values can overflow an `int`, but that requires a fairly esoteric C implementation.

Comment: Thanks Eric Postpischil :)

Answer (score 6):

The specification for `strcmp` in the C standard says only that it “returns an integer greater than, equal to, or less than zero, accordingly as the string pointed to by **s1** is greater than, equal to, or less than the string pointed to by **s2**” ([C 2011 N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 7.24.4.2 3, C 2018 *ibid*).

You may not rely on more specific behavior, such as returning a specific value, unless you have an additional guarantee from your C implementation.

Answer (score 5):

All that the specifications say is that strcmp will return a number "less than", "greater than" or "equal to" zero depending on the result of the comparison.

I'm not sure why you believe that the difference should be 5.

Comment: the ASCII difference between "i" and "d" is 5 , .i.e., inputtext -->i and difference text-->d and hence i have given as 5.

Answer (score 3):

I think you misunderstood what [strcmp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html) does:

> #### `int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);`
>
> Upon completion, [`strcmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html) shall return an integer greater than, equal to, or less than 0, if the string pointed to by `s1` is greater than, equal to, or less than the string pointed to by `s2`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/):

About `strcmp` return value

> Returns an integral value indicating the relationship between the strings:
>    A zero value indicates that both strings are equal.
>    A value greater than zero indicates that the first character that does not match has a greater value in str1 than in str2; And a value less than zero indicates the opposite.

Comment: Somebody's allergic to `cplusplus.com`?

Comment: I did not down vote, but this is a C question, not a C++ question. Also, cplusplus.com is not an authoritative reference; the C++ standard would be preferred.

Answer (score -1):

That's because `strcmp` return an int: negative if first is less than second, positive non-zero if second is less that first and 0 if equal.

Comment: It is better to say "I don't know" than to give misleading information. The K&R C programming book even gives a reference implementation that merely returns the subtracted value of one character from another in the event that it is non-zero.